# why the "reorder" in ggplot did not show the mean value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning `ggplot2` with the `mtcars`example:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs)

#it shows the mean value 
qplot(reorder(mtcars$vs, mtcars$mpg))

#it do not show the mean value, Why?
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=reorder(vs, mpg), y=mpg, fill=vs))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

How to show the mean value as `qplot` using `ggplot2`?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Please remember the new ggplot 2 (2.0) had it's documentation updated to really de-emphasize using `qplot`.  Neither of your plots has any concept of "mean" associated with it.

Comment: I don't understand "it shows the mean value". Please clarify.

Comment: What makes you think the initial plot is showing you the mean value? It is showing the counts of different factor levels - 18 and 14 respectively. It is equivalent to this: ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=reorder(vs, mpg))) + geom_histogram(). The second plot is summing up the mpg values per each value of vs value. Try tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$vs, sum). These are the two values that are getting plotted in the bar plot. If you area really trying to get averages by vs value, then you should use: ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=vs, y=mpg, fill=vs)) + geom_boxplot().

Comment: You should post that as an answer. It is worth something.

Comment: @user3949008. You should post that as an answer. It is worth something, had never seen `reorder` before.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think the initial plot is showing you the mean value? It is showing the counts of different factor levels - 18 and 14 respectively. It is equivalent to this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=reorder(vs, mpg))) + geom_histogram().
```

The second plot is summing up the mpg values per each value of vs value. Try:

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$vs, sum)
```

These are the two values that are getting plotted in the bar plot. If you area really trying to get averages by vs value, then you should use:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=vs, y=mpg, fill=vs)) + geom_boxplot()
```